# Why is .patch:nth-last-of-type(x) not counting elements having only .patch class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I’m trying to select the 3 last elements having the patch class inside a zone. There might be or not a trailing fourth element which is not a .patch, but it seems to interfere with the counting.

```css
.nyz_action_zone .patch:nth-last-of-type(1) {
  filter: none !important;
}

.nyz_action_zone .patch:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  filter: grayscale(0.5);
}

.nyz_action_zone .patch:nth-last-of-type(3) {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

.patch {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
}

.nyz_action_zone {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
}

.token_neutral {
  background: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="action_zone_16" class="nyz_action_zone">
  <div class="patch">patch 1 not targeted</div>
  <div class="patch">patch 2 applys last-of-type(3)</div>
  <div class="patch">patch 3 applys last-of-type(2)</div>
  <div id="token_neutral" class="token_neutral"> </div>
</div>
```

I’m expecting the first patch to be targeted by .nyz_action_zone div.patch:nth-last-of-type(3),
the second one by .nyz_action_zone div.patch:nth-last-of-type(2)
and the third one by .nyz_action_zone div.patch:nth-last-of-type(1)
but it’s not what happens because of the presence of the token_neutral div. If I change it to any other element it works as expected, but I don’t undestand why.

You can see what happens here : https://codepen.io/mizutismask/pen/jOdqVgv
I should obtain a gradient but can’t figure how. I must be missing something about nth-last-of-type use.

Comment: @Austin — `nth-last-of-type`'s arguments are `<an-plus-b> | even | odd`, not a selector. `nth-last-of-type` targets types (like `div` and `li`) and only types.